# Why package Share flutter isn't defined?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem when running my flutter Apps.
I have a class _GoldProductPageState that use package Share.

```
Error: The getter 'Share' isn't defined for the class '_GoldProductPageState'.
 '_GoldProductPageState' is from 'package:tanamduit/View/Pages/gold/GoldProductPage.dart' ('lib/View/Pages/gold/GoldProductPage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'Share'. onPressed: () => Share.share(uri.toString()),
```

This is my Code where i use the share package in GoldProductPage.dart:

```
GestureDetector(
       child: Container(
       height: 50,
       width: 100,
       child: FutureBuilder<Uri>(
       future: _dynamicLinkService.createDynamicLink(),
       builder: (context, snapshot) {
       if(snapshot.hasData) {
       Uri uri = snapshot.data;
       return FloatingActionButton(
       backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
       onPressed: () => Share.share(uri.toString()),
       child: Text('Share'),    
        );
         } else {
           return Container();
              }
            }
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

and this is the code for the class '_GoldProductPageState':

```
class _GoldProductPageState extends State<GoldProductPage> {
  final BaseDynamicLinks _dynamicLinkService = BaseDynamicLinks();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        return;
      },
```

This is the pubspec.yaml :

```
 responsive_widgets: ^2.0.1
 flutter_screenutil: ^1.0.2
 toggle_switch: "^0.1.4"
 font_awesome_flutter: ^8.8.1
 share: ^0.6.4+3
      
dev_dependencies:
  test: ^1.5.1
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

You can see my full code in here:
https://pastebin.com/5ry5i7et

What is my wrong?
Thankyou

Comment: Can you post the lines where you include the package (pubspec.yaml and import)?

Comment: done, i already update the pubspec.yaml, but i dont make all because too many, so i just update for the package Share.
and about the import, you can see in link, on pastebin.com above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
onPressed: () 
{
  Share.share(uri.toString());
},
```

Comment: I've changed it, but the error is still the same.
any solutions?

Comment: wait a minute, have you checked the package is imported to your class?

Comment: thnkyou bro, my bad, your answer was true